# how can one use dask.dataframe with custom dsk graphs

Tags: python, dask

I'll try to rephrase my question:

How do I combine a dask.dataframe along with a function like zip?

assume we have a file named "accounts.0.csv" with the following data

```
id,names,amount
352,Dan,4837
387,Tim,208
42,Jerry,21
129,Patricia,284
```

i wrote this code

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import itertools
from dask.threaded import get


df = dd.read_csv('accounts.0.csv')

dsk = {'a': (dd.read_csv,('accounts.0.csv')),       
       'b': (itertools.repeat,(True)),       
       'res': (zip, 'a'[id],'b')       
       }

get(dsk, 'res')
```

This code should generate something like this:

```
352, True
387, True
42 , True
129, True
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: what are you trying to do here?  what should the zip be operating over and why do you want to do it in parallel?

Comment: this is part of bigger a graph. this example just show the problem , it doesn't have a real meanning. my question is how do you join/zip together a dask.series and an iterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip is intended for Python iterators, not Pandas or Dask DataFrames.

To implement your example above you could use the [`assign`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame.assign) method

#### pandas

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   x
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [4]: df.assign(y=True)
Out[4]: 
   x     y
0  1  True
1  2  True
2  3  True
```

#### dask.dataframe

```
In [5]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [6]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)

In [7]: ddf.assign(y=True).compute()
Out[7]: 
   x     y
0  1  True
1  2  True
2  3  True
```

#### Generally don't mix graphs with dataframes

The dictionary-style graphs like `dsk = {...}` should not be mixed with the dask.dataframe objects.  The dask.dataframe objects use the graphs internally.  They should not be placed within them.

Comment: Thanks @MRocklin, i hoped that i could use dataframes with a code like the one found in Dask's documentation http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/custom-graphs.html . if i want to use this template (of load,clean,analyze,store) , could i use it with pandas.dataframe?

Comment: Does the following documentation commit answer your question?  https://github.com/blaze/dask/commit/0bb7189738134e4f9596ee0142a47e6d2d37e4b3

Comment: partially , i see that you can load pandas's dataframe . can you use graphs like dsk {...} to manipulate them. you wrote "don't mix graphs with dataframes".

Comment: Don't mix graphs and dask.dataframes.  The graphs that define dask.dataframes contain pandas.dataframes.

Comment: greate , Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to "lift" (to borrow terminology from Monads in Haskell) the iterator out from inside the computation, `dask` builds the list of tasks before starting any computation and hence you need to get at the iterator from "outside" any computation.  Your call to `compute` gets you "outside" dask which is why that worked.

I'm not sure of a good example because what you'd do depends on what other tasks are next, but as a not very nice but minimal example:

```
import dask.imperative as di

arr = []
for col in df:
    arr.append(ddf[col].map(lambda x: (x,True)))
task = di.value([])+arr
```

creates a list of tasks that map over values within each series.  The then uses the imperative module to wrap everything in a task—could't find a nicer way of doing this, sorry!

You can then `compute` the task to get a list of series back, or use it in something else.

Comment: Thanks @Sam Mason , i'm sorry for not being clear, English is not my first language. my problem is iterating over dask.dataframe like i would do with pandas's dataframe. i edit my question , i hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

#### Rephrase Question

I'll try to rephrase your question as the following:

*How do I combine a dask.dataframe along with a custom dask graph?*

```
df = dd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
dsk = {'x': (add, 1, 2)}
```

The dataframe is a high-level collection, the dask graph is more low-level.  We'll have to bring one to the others' level.

#### Use dask imperative

We could use dask.imperative to turn the custom function into a high-level dsak object

```
# dsk = {'x': (inc, 1, 2)}
x = dask.do(add)(1, 2)
```

Then you can use `dask.compute` on either one or both of the objects.

```
x_result = dask.compute(x)
or
df_result = dask.compute(df)
or
x_result, df_result = dask.compute(x, df)
```

#### Use low-level dask graphs everywhere

The low-level graph and final keys for any DataFrame object are accessible from the `.dask` and `._keys()` attributes.

```
from toolz import merge
graph = merge(dsk, df.dask)  # merge both graphs together
keys = ['x', df._keys()]     # final keys to compute

x_results, df_results = get(graph, keys)

df_result = df._finalize(df_results)  # turn graph outputs back to pandas dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks @MRocklin , i'm sorry for not being clear, English is not my first language. my problem is using dask.dataframe with zip like i would do with pandas's dataframe. i edit my question , i hope it is clearer now